# retrieving two variables at the time in list (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

```
dict = {'key':['10', '11']}

for var_i, var_j in dict['key']:
    print var_i
    print var_j
```

Running the code above gives me the output below.

```
1
0
1
1
```

How can I get an output looking like this?

```
10
11
```

[EDIT]
The length of the variables may differ, they're aren't always two characters. I'm looking for var_i to be the first element of the list and var_j to be the second.

Comment: Why are you separating the digits if you want to concatenate them afterwards?

Comment: You aren't actually retrieving two variables, you are retrieving a string and then accessing it's first and second character

Comment: Does your edit means you want only first two elements of your list in case it has more elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looping on the characters of the strings.

since you don't care about the keys, but only the values, just do this instead:

```
d = {'key':['10', '11']}

for v in d.values():
    # v is the list, now loop to print each item
    for i in v:
        print(i)
```

Comment: I did for v, i in d.values(): print v, print i and got exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to just iterate over the value of `dict` with key as `key` like:

```
>>> my_dict = {'key':['10', '11']}
>>> for i in my_dict['key']:
...     print i
...
10
11
```

The syntax that you have is generally used for unwinding the elements of list as:

```
>>> a, b = my_dict['key']
>>> print a   # value of index `0`
10
>>> print b   # value of index `1`
11
```

---

**Note:** Do not use *dict* as variable name as [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) is built-in type in Python

Comment: thanks for your edit, but now that python 3 is becoming the norm, it's better to write `print(i)` both for python 2 & python 3. `print i` is illegal with python 3 so I had to rollback your edit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I believe better way is to mention it as comment in the answer, with both syntax. Isn't it? Because the OP is related to Python 2, it should be as the part of main code :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't name things with names that already have meaning.  `d['key']` is equal to `['10', '11']`.  So your `for` loop pulls out `'10'` and then unpacks it into `var_i, var_j`.  Just do a `for` loop with no unpacking.

```
for v in d['key']:
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, just use a for loop.

```
>>for v1 in dict['key']:
    print(v1)
```

:D